# How can I print an item in a website using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I need a way to search in a website for a specific keyword and output it to the console.

The xpath:

```
//*[@id="tab_actions_pending"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/p
```

I need the script to try to find the word **100%** in that **xpath** and if it doesnt find it will pass and exit the script!

The website image with inspect open:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in xpath is done via find_elements_by_xpath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '100%')]")
```

Comment: So I made it like this: `print(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab_actions_pending"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/p[contains(text(), "100")]'))` but its nt printing like true or false is that supost ? Its printing `[]`